# Having Trouble Removing Duplicates From A List

Tags: c#

I have a list of like 3000 items, and I think there are a ton of duplicates. So to make my program run faster, I want to delete them. This is the code along with my function, which when I run the program the text file is empty.

```
List<string> allCombos = new List<string>();
        string here = RemoveTheSame(allCombos, allCombos);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Hodag Image Storage Folder\creo.txt", here);
```

//////////////////////////////

```
        private string RemoveTheSame(List<String> lista, List<String> listb)
    {
        List<String> newList = lista;

        newList.AddRange(lista);
        for(int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
            int a = 0;
            for(int ii = 0; ii < listb.Count; ii++)
            {
                if(lista[i] == listb[ii])
                {
                    a += 1;
                    if(a >= 2)
                    {
                        newList.RemoveAt(ii);
                        a = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        string wat = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < newList.Count; i++)
        {
            wat += newList[i] + " ";
        }


        return wat;
    }
```

Comment: Why not simply `allCombos = allCombos.Distinct().ToList()`?

Comment: Typo? `string here = RemoveTheSame(allCombos, allCombos);` looks **strange**: you, probably want to pass **different** collections into the method - `string here = RemoveTheSame(allCombos, rerefenceCombos);`

Comment: Since you're comparing the same list twice, all items will be duplicated right? That means you *should* have an empty output.

Comment: I'm pretty amateur, I've yet to learn all the fundies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see from `RemoveTheSame(List<String> lista, List<String> listb)` you can have *three* possible cases:

You have *two* lists: `allCombos` and `referenceList` you want to return all the items from `allCombos` which are not in `referenceList`:

```
  allCombos:     [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 5]
  referenceList: [1, 2, 4]
  result:        [3, 5, 5] // 1, 2, 4 removed
```

Solution:

```
   var hashSet = new hashSet(referenceList); 

   allCombos.RemoveAll(item => hashSet.Contains(item));
```

You have *two* lists: `allCombos` and `referenceList` you want to return all the items from `allCombos` which are not in `referenceList`; all duplicates from `allCombos` should be removed as well:

```
  allCombos:     [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 5]
  referenceList: [1, 2, 4]
  result:        [3, 5]    // duplicate - second "5" removed
```

Solution:

```
   allCombos = allCombos
     .Except(referenceList)
     .ToList();
```

You have a *single* `allCombos` list only, and want to remove duplicates from it:

```
   allCombos:     [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 5]
   result:        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // second 1 and 5 are removed
```

Solution:

```
   allCombos = allCombos
     .Distinct()
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, why can't you use Linq [`Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which will retrieve only the unique items from the input list

```
var distinctItems = allCombos.Distinct().ToList();
```